# Find and replace matching multiple parameters from list (or another file)

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I wrote a simple shell script that works but it's terribly inefficient. It takes too long to run on larger files. I'm looking for a faster solution.

Sample input files:

**data.csv**:

```
1,data,data
3,data,data
4,data,data
9,data,data
...
```

**matches.txt**:

```
3
9
16
17
...
```

The script I wrote iterates through each item in `matches.txt`. It uses `sed` to match the beginning of the lines in the csv file and comments them out by prepending `**`.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' :; XYZ=$(<matches.txt)
for id in ${XYZ[@]}
do
  sed -i '' "${id}s/^**//" data.csv
done
```

I'm using OS X so `sed` parameters are slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than calling `sed` in a loop you can use this awk:

```
awk -F ',' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++; next} $1 in a{$0 = "**" $0} 1' matches.txt data.csv
1,data,data
**3,data,data
4,data,data
**9,data,data
```

To save output from `awk`:

```
awk -F ',' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++; next} $1 in a{$0 = "**" $0} 1' matches.txt data.csv > _tmp
mv _tmp data.csv
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F ','` - Use field separator as comma
- `FNR==NR` - Execute this block for first file
- `{a[$1]++; next}` - Create an array with key as `$1` from first file and move to next line
- `$1 in a{$0 = "**" $0}` - For the 2nd file if 1st field is in array `a` then prepend `**` in current line.
- `1` - default awk action (print the line)

Comment: Wow! Ok that locates the lines much faster, however, I need to modify the original file. The command I'm using does an in-place revision. Is there something similar for `awk`? And can you explain the command?

Comment: I have added details in answer and also a way to save output.

Comment: If you are using `gnu-awk > 4.1.0` then you can use: `awk -i inplace -F ',' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++; next} $1 in a{print "**" $0}' matches.txt data.csv`

Comment: The `-i` option is not available for `awk` on OS X. From reading the manual, I don't know if in-place modification is available. [awk page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html)

Comment: On OSX it is not available that's why I mentioned gnu-awk version in my comment. I am using it on my OSX via `home brew` though. You can just use temp file way to migrate changes back to original file.

Comment: How do I use the temp file to migrate changes? (Without just replacing the original file)

Comment: No, that replaces the file.